# Zurb Foundation 4 position section titles on the right of the screen

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I am trying to use sections to create navigation on a simple page, however I need it to be on the right of the screen. The default layout provided by Foundation when using "vertical-tabs" is ["tabs on the left, content on the right"](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/section.html).

```
<div class="section-container vertical-tabs" data-section="vertical-tabs">
  <section>
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Section title 1</a></p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>Content of section 1.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Section title 2</a></p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>Content of section 2.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

How do I switch the layout to "tabs on the right, content on the left"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the specific selector chain to override the Foundation CSS, or do something clever in SASS, but this works at my end with Foundation 4.2.1 or something relatively recent.

```
.section-container.vertical-tabs>section>.title{
left:auto;
right:0;
}
.section-container.vertical-tabs>section>.content{
left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want to use the "Tabs" option:

```
    <div class="section-container tabs" data-section="tabs">
  <section class="active">
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Section 1</a></p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>Content of section 1.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Section 2</a></p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>Content of section 2.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

And this CSS to override Section.js settings:

```
.section-container > section > .title:nth-child(1){
left:auto!important;
right:86px;
background:#fff;
}
.section-container > section > .content{
left:0;
}
.section-container > section:nth-child(2) >.title{
right:0px!important;
}

.section-container > section.active >.title a{
background:#404040!important;
color:#fff!important
}
```

That worked for me! Hope it helps